# Can't Restore Database Because of Rogue Log File

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, restore, log

Someone, somehow, made a database disappear from SQL Server 2008 R2. I'm assuming it was dropped, because it doesn't show in SSMS in the Object Explorer's list of databases. Let's call the database "Rogue". Now, there is a rogue log file, "Rogue_log.ldf" on the server's file system. The file cannot be deleted via Explorer.

Here is the restore script. Note that I tried to run it without "MOVE" first, and then got the error further below in this post. Yes, it's "Logs" and not "Log" in the path (don't ask).

```
RESTORE DATABASE Rogue
FROM DISK = 'E:\Rogue.bak'
WITH MOVE 'Rogue' TO 'E:\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Rogue.mdf', 
MOVE 'Rogue_log' TO 'D:\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Logs\Rogue_log.ldf',
RECOVERY, REPLACE
GO
```

Trying to run the script is giving the following error:

> Msg 3634, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The operating system returned the
>   error '5(Access is denied.)' while attempting
>   'RestoreContainer::ValidateTargetForCreation' on
>   'D:\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Logs\Rogue_log.ldf'. Msg 3156, Level
>   16, State 8, Line 1 File 'RGA_log' cannot be restored to
>   'D:\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Logs\Rogue_log.ldf'. Use WITH MOVE to
>   identify a valid location for the file. Msg 3119, Level 16, State 1,
>   Line 1 Problems were identified while planning for the RESTORE
>   statement. Previous messages provide details. Msg 3013, Level 16,
>   State 1, Line 1 RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

I can restore a backup from Rogue.bak if I change the log file name to Rogue1_log.ldf (Star Wars puns NOT intended.) Can anyone help me figure out what's going on with this rogue Rogue_log.ldf on the server file system?

Comment: Did the account you used to try to delete the leftover log file have sufficient permission to do so?

Comment: Run Process Explorer to see what is using that file.

Comment: Did you put a different location for log file when tried with move?

Comment: If rogue_log.ldf doesn't work but rogue1_log.ldf works, then it's almost certain that there's already a file in that folder named rogue_log.ldf. Try moving it first (and if moving it fails, then you have two similar databases and should decide for yourself which one should be able to have a log file with that name). REPLACE only works if that file is currently attached *and* belongs to the same database. Does anything show up with that name in `master.sys.master_files`? Could it be attached to a different instance?

Comment: Are you certain SSMS is connected to the server using an account that is a member of the sysadmin group?  Perhaps the account simply doesn't have access to "see" the database?

Comment: @AaronBertrand yes, there is a file named rogue_log.ldf in the folder. At the file system level, I can't delete it, even though I have local admin. At the SQL Server level, the DB restore won't overwrite/reuse it.

Comment: Local admin can't break SQL Server's lock on the file. It is clearly in use by SQL Server - have you looked for that file name in `master.sys.master_files`, as I suggested earlier? Have you considered just giving the new database different, non-conflicting file names?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yes, I looked in master_files, but it's not listed. I did a restore under non-conflicting names, but I would like to figure this out because .... because I gotta find the solution :)

Comment: Maybe it's from a different instance of SQL Server. Or maybe something else has the file locked (check out sysinternals tools).

Answer (score 2):

I'd bet the database didn't actually get dropped, and is still in use by SQL.

Not sure why it isn't showing up in SSMS, but run the following query to see what database is still using it:

```
SELECT database_id, DB_NAME(database_id) AS DBName, name AS LogicalName, type_desc,
physical_name, convert(numeric(10,1),(size/128.0/1024.0)) SizeGB
FROM master.sys.master_files
ORDER BY database_id, type_desc desc, name
```

Is your Rogue database in the list?

If you just do `SELECT * FROM master.sys.databases`, does it show Rogue? What does it show as the `user_access_desc` and `state_desc`?

What does the SQL errorlog say during the time in question? It should mention a database drop or change in status.

Answer (score 2):

I would try

1. Restart the sql service and see whether the db re-appears in SSMS. If yes, just drop it using drop database
2. If step 1 does not work, stop the sql service and then delete the log file via File Explorer (better rename it for backup purpose), then restart the sql service, and try to do the restore again.

I once encountered a similar issue, and we ended by stopping the sql service and then copy both the data and log file to a similar sql instance and then attach them back to a new db and then using dbcc to fix some data corruption issue (with data loss) and then continue our work (it was a non-prod db and we did not have any backup)

Comment: Did both. Even with the services stopped, I can't delete it from the file system, even though I can create files in that location, etc (I have local admin).

Comment: If you cannot delete it after sql service stops, can it be probably your permission issue for that folder, i.e. you can create new files but cannot delete any existing file? Can you ask your system admin people to do it? or can you rename it?